# Creating a Range in VBA

Tags: vba, range

I'm working on my first VBA function. The goal is to have a function that accepts two integers as inputs, and outputs an array containing all the integers in between the two inputs (end-points included).

Example: If I input 5 and 9, the output should be an array of 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

VBA doesn't seem to have any of the objects or functions I'm used to in other languages.  Python has a range() function, but most other languages I know about have list-like types which can be appended to.  How does this work in VBA?

I'm not looking to create an Excel range, but rather an array which contains a range between two values.

Comment: In VBA you `ReDim` an array to the required size and then populate it.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**if you asking about Cells multiple range then you can use this:**

```
Sub test1()
    Dim nStart&, nEnd&
    Dim Rng As Range
    nStart = 5: nEnd = 9
    Set Rng = Range("A" & nStart)
    While nStart <> nEnd
        Set Rng = Union(Rng, Range("A" & nStart + 1))
        nStart = nStart + 1
    Wend
    Debug.Print Rng.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

*output*

`A5:A9`

**if you asking not about cells.range but about an array range then you can use this:**

```
Sub test2()
    Dim nStart&, nEnd&
    Dim Rng() As String, i&
    nStart = 5: nEnd = 9
    For i = 0 To nEnd - nStart
        ReDim Preserve Rng(i)
        Rng(i) = nStart
        nStart = nStart + 1
    Next i
    For i = 0 To UBound(Rng)
        Debug.Print Rng(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

or you can use this:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim nStart&, nEnd&
    Dim Rng As Object, key As Variant
    Set Rng = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    nStart = 5: nEnd = 9
    While nStart <> nEnd + 1
        Rng.Add nStart, Nothing
        nStart = nStart + 1
    Wend
    For Each key In Rng
        Debug.Print key
    Next key
    Set Rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

*output for both last two variants will be the same*

```
 5 
 6 
 7 
 8 
 9
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is pretty good. I'll clarify in my question that I don't mean an Excel range.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function RangeArray(startAt As Long, endAt As Long) As Long()
    Dim arr() As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    n = endAt - startAt
    ReDim arr(0 To n)
    For i = 0 To n
        arr(i) = startAt + i
    Next i
    RangeArray = arr
End Function

Sub Tester()
    Dim arr
    arr = RangeArray(5, 10)
    Debug.Print arr(LBound(arr)), arr(UBound(arr))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Applies only in the context of Excel** (not sure based on question and tags)

If you want a one-liner that doesn't deal with arrays, you can take advantage of the `ROW` function and `Application.Evaluate` within Excel.

**Code**

```
Function RangeArr(int_start As Integer, int_end As Integer) As Variant

    RangeArr = Application.Transpose( _
                    Application.Evaluate("=ROW(" & int_start & ":" & int_end & ")"))

End Function
```

**Results**

[image: array results]